# Rewriting 2D array of integers to bitmap in Python using PyQT

Tags: python, arrays, qt, pyqt

I want to do convert array of integers into some sort of 'picture' using PyQt (I've decided to do my app in Qt). I have array like this:

```
Array = [
[0,0,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,0,1],
[0,1,0,1,0],
[0,0,1,0,0]]
```

Now I want to rewrite it into picture, by replacing each integer by for example square 10x10 pixels. I have definition for each value in array in RGB. What's more This is some kind of game of life, so it must refresh on each step and shouldn't be slow. Maybe somethinf similar to OpenCV?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Mateusz

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do the above with [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsscene.html) and [QGraphicsView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsview.html). In order to get good performance, you'll want to call [setViewport(QGLWidget())](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewport) on your `QGraphicsView` instance. Create a subclass of [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsitem.html) to represent an element in your array. You'll then even be able to animate the changes if you want.

If you do want animations or are demonstrating some progression such as in Conway's Game of Life you might also want to take a look at [QTimeLine](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtimeline.html).

You can look up the equivalent python-based documentation on either the [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/classes.html)<sup>*</sup> or [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/) websites. Both PyQt and PySide use a nearly identical API so for most everything you can use them interchangeably.

<sup>*</sup>*Note: The PyQt website is inaccessible at the time of this writing*

Comment: Thanks for links, but my app is in Python. Are all this classes present in PyQt?

Comment: Both PyQt and PySide have support for the classes referenced above. I'll edit to Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use QT’s graphics libraries for performance. Another, maybe simpler way could be to use PIL (Python Imaging Library) or some Python bindings to the ImageMagick or MagickWand library (I haven't found a good and current one) and use NumPy’s arrays for calculations and manipulation, and draw on a surface or canvas using PyGame, QT or some other GUI toolkit.

In PIL there is `PIL.Image.fromarray(np_array, 'RGBA')`, that reads suitable NumPy arrays – the datatype must usually be `dtype=int8` and the shape is `(height, width, n_channels)`.

For a very simple graphics format that uses ascii byte values, see [NetPBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format).